# matplotlib 3d animation embed in PyQt5 GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib

My friend an I are working on embedding an 3D animation of the Lorenz attractor in a GUI with PyQt5. When testing the code, we were using matplolib.pyplot and no problem occured. But, when running our code in a PyQt5 matplotlib embedded figure, we get this timer error from the backend_qt5agg

```
self.timer.timeout.disconnect(self.show_time)
    TypeError: 'method' object is not connected
```

So, if u had this type of error, what would you reccomend us to do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help *("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error (include the full error traceback, not only the last line of it) and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in PyQt5, u can do animations with QtCores timer and this helps to transcend the error that occured when i was trying to run the animation with matplotlib's Funcanimation. Here's a link which show's an example of dynamic plotting : http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html